# How to avoid faces overlapping when bridging edge loops

Tags: modifiers, faces, normals

I want to create a bottom wall and to do it i add a circle and then use "bridge edge loop"

[image]

But the result is strange:

[image]

I don't want a face also **inside** circle (beacause it will be a hole).

I hope can you help me and sorry for my english

Comment: you don't need the central circle, just extrude with E, press enter, scale inwards, then W > LoopTools > Circle. Enable the LoopTools addon if it's not the case already

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate that loop and Scale it down.

Make it a circle.

Select both loops and apply the bridge.

See the images below.

[image]